# Create an ML model to continue given pattern

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'm new to the ML so don't laugh, but I'm trying to create a model to continue a given pattern (some numbers like 1, 5, 9, etc.)... I've tried to use Keras but without success. Could anyone help?

Comment: Hello, please read this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your question

Comment: You can start googling for [time series prediction](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)